# About level curves of a continuous function in a real square, and connectivity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

Assume f is a continuous function on the (unit) square in real plane. Name the edges N,S,E and W in the natural way. Assume f is >0 at W edge and <0 on E edge.

Intuitively it is clear that there is (at least one) level curve for level=0 that connects N edge to S edge.

Without requiring more smoothness than just continuity, I think I can prove that the open set where abs(f) < eps    (small eps>0)  always contains a connecting path, with a finite set of horizontal and vertical legs.

This seems like a very natural generalization of 1-D intermediate value theorem. Are there elementary "well-known" textbook results (meaning with an elementary short proof fitting to calculus or analysis, not advanced topology)?  Is there any "obvious" proof only requiring continuity, no differentiability?

Comment: By the usual intermediate value theorem, there are such points on both N and S. Due to continuity and the other boundary conditions at E and W, such points can not cover all of N or of S. The connecting path in the open set does not need to reach zero at ends.